# Finance Calculations in Vue.js - Using computed methods

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I've created a form with asset details on using Vue, and several fields to calculate the asset cost and depreciation.

However the `deprec_carried_forward` field seems to be concatenating the `deprec_brought_fwd` value and the `deprec_charges` values together.

It seems to be because the `deprec_charges` value is being returned from its own computed method, as the `deprec_disposals value` is typed in and that gets subtracted from the value in `deprec_carried_forward` correctly.

e.g.

**Depreciation Brought Forward**: (typed) 10

**Depreciation Charges**: (Computed) 3.3

**Depreciation Disposals**: (typed) 2

**Depreciation Carried Forward**: 101.3 (computed: should be 11.3)

My computed methods are:

```
    computed: {
        costs_carried_fwd: function(){
            return this.financial(this.costs_brought_fwd + this.cost_additions - this.cost_disposals);
        },
        deprec_charges: function(){
            return this.financial(this.costs_carried_fwd * 0.33);
        },
        deprec_carried_fwd: function(){
            return this.financial(this.deprec_brought_fwd + this.deprec_charges - this.deprec_disposals);
        },
        net_book_value: function(){
            return this.financial(this.costs_carried_fwd - this.deprec_carried_fwd);
        }
    },
```

See jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nickdavies07/gkj6Ldf4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `financial` method uses toFixed, which returns a string.

This is fine when you are just doing one call with it. But the second you start adding and subtracting them, you end up concatenating string instead of adding numbers.

You need to do your formatting after all numeric calculations have been performed.

I’m not familiar enough with Vue to know the correct place to put your number to string with two decimal places logic, but in other MVC frameworks (like Rails), you’d use a helper method in the view for that.

Edit:
Also it’s worth noting that especially since this is a financial application, you REALLY need to delay any number truncations until the very end, or else you’ll end up with rounding errors as you perform more math operations.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise toFixed() returned a string. And thanks for the advice on delaying the truncations, I'll definitely do that.

Comment: Definitely. No problem!

Comment: @NickDavies would you mind accepting this as the “answer”?